# Angular - disable send button when form is invalid

Tags: angular

Hello I have this form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="create()" #form="ngForm">
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data.name"
 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" #name="ngModel" required>
<p *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched) && 
 name.errors.required" class="text-danger">Error</p>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" 
  [disabled]="form.invalid">Send</button>
</form>
```

And I have a problem with validations. Validation is ok on input, but button is still enabled. I would like to disable button when input is empty. How to disable button when form is invalid? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the input element to be considered in the form validation, you should remove the `standalone` option and give a `name` attribute to the element:

```
<input type="text" name="nameInput" [(ngModel)]="data.name" #name="ngModel" required ...>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-blur-g1eqkl) for a demo.

---

Here is a description of the `standalone` option given in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties):

> standalone: Defaults to false. If this is set to true, the ngModel
>   will not register itself with its parent form, and will act as if it's
>   not in the form.